# Responsive design and fluid images with floated divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header that uses images to fluidly adapt to smaller screens such as smartphones, but I can't make it work properly.

Let's assume to see it properly in the fiddle that we have a max-width of the container of 500px, and the images are 85px (left aligned) and 185px (right aligned) width, leaving 250px blank in the middle for resolutions higher than 500px. Actual sizes are 2x but isn't relevant.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div></div>
        <img src="..."/>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div></div>
        <img src="..."/>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:500px;
    min-height:50px;
    height:20%;
    max-height:90px;
    background-color:#0FF;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    height:calc(100% - 5px);
}
#left div {
    height:calc(100% - 73px);
}
#left img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:85px;
    height:auto;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:calc(100% - 5px);
    position:relative;
}
#right div {
    height:calc(50% - (25px + 5px)/2);
}
#right img {
    max-width:185px;
    max-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:right;
}
</style>
```

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pinx0/xGPvM/6/

Resolutions higher than 270px wide work as they should. Vertical scaling works fine also.

Now, look what happens with a low resolution like 250px:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pinx0/xGPvM/5/

The floating items moves to the next line instead of scaling down and fit in one line.

Expected result is both images reducing its size as resolution comes narrower.

Comment: Try not to use `calc` unless it's really needed. It can really slow down a webpage, as it's usually evaluated every single reflow. If you want responsive design, do it with media queries, not `calc` values.

Comment: But media queries make changes in steps, i was looking for something more fluid, proportional if you want. Anyways, that not the root of the issue.

Comment: In that case, you can set an image's `max-width` to `auto`, and (layout depending) it will scale with the site smoothly. Resize this website (http://rainbowjam.net/) and see that the header image just rescales with the browser.

Comment: That website is what I'm trying to achieve. But the problem is in my case there are 2 images in floated divs. That's what is stopping me. If it only were one image is easier just like that website.

Comment: What you could look into doing is having it set up in CSS tables instead of floated `<div>`s. You'd set the width of the table to `100%` and the width of the smaller image to what you'd prefer it to be. Then set the `max-width` on both to be `100%` and it should scale properly, even without media queries.

Answer (score 0):

See This Fiddle.

jsfiddle.net/xGPvM/7/

It displays the image fine in 250px resolutions. Check this. You have to give the image width in percent. It automatically in low resolution well.